# Spread a destructuring to avoid a duplication

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring, spread-syntax

Is there a way to avoid the duplication of `competenceList[competenceKey]` (object) in lines `:5` and `:6`, keeping the same object on return without using variable declaration?

```js
const func = ({
    entities: { competence: competenceList },
    timesheet: { management: { competences: competenceKey } },
}) => ({
    employeeKey: competenceList[competenceKey].employee,
    payrollEnd: competenceList[competenceKey].competenceEnd,
});
```

Comment: Don't try so hard to avoid the variable declaration. It will be much more readable with it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, specially in this nested scenario. Asking just for curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible by using a computed property name:

```
const func = ({
    timesheet: { management: { competences } },
    entities: { competence: { [competences]: competence },
}) => ({
    employeeKey: competence.employee,
    payrollEnd: competence.competenceEnd,
});
```

but I wouldn't recommend this as it's not really readable. Just write

```
function func({timesheet, entities}) {
    const competence = entities.competence[timesheet.management.compentences];
    return {
        employeeKey: competence.employee,
        payrollEnd: competence.competenceEnd,
    };
}
```